# json_decode not working

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{"easyStoreRelayList":[],"DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup":"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio \"ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO\" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon.","warehouseRelayList":[],"DecathlonStoreAreaRememberMe":"Riconoscimi alla prossima visita","DecathlonWarehouseParcelSection":"Magazzini","DecathlonStoreParcelSection":"Negozio DECATHLON","DecathlonEasyStoreParcelSection":"Negozio DECATHLON EASY","geoName":"Alessandria","physicalStoreList":[["PS_IT_45","Serravalle Scrivia (Alessandria)","471",null,"7",null]]}
```

This is my code to try and have it in json format so that it's easier to me to work whit the info.

```
//$html is the var containing the original string befora trying to parse it to JSON

    $html = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $html));
    $obj = json_decode($html,true);
    $obj = rtrim($obj, "\0");


    echo $obj["DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup"];
    if(json_last_error() == 4){
        echo "ERROR";
    }
```

I keep getting the error of: Illegal string offset 'DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup', and the error 4 as "json_last_error".

Anyone kwnos what it could be, that is not parsing corretly the json??

Comment: Start with a `var_dump($obj)` before you do anything else. What does that give you?!

Comment: Also, `rtrim` on an ***array*** is purely nonsense; did you mean to do that *before* you `json_decode` the string?

Comment: var_dump prints NULL

Comment: Then go further back step by step; where do your variables deviate from what you expect them to be? This is known as *basic debugging*.

Comment: @deceze thx 4 the info man...

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is this line:

```
$html = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $html));
```

You do not need to do any of this stuff when parsing JSON. If the JSON is valid, then the above line will make it invalid. If it is invalid when you get it, then nothing in that line will be enough to fix it.

So the first thing to do is remove that line.

As it turns out, your JSON is also invalid. It contains double-quote characters in a string that is bounded by double-quotes.

```
"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio "ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon."
```

This part of your JSON is not valid, and cannot be parsed by `json_encode()`.

However, you can't easily fix this in your PHP program. You need to fix the system that is generating this invalid JSON. Once it arrives in your PHP code as an invalid string, there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio "ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon."
```

Here. Look you have used the same quotes inside of your main quotes so AQUISTA ON LINE... is considered to be out of the string.
Transform it to :

> "Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento
>   effettua il servizio 'ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO' oppure non
>   sono presenti negozi Decathlon."

Edit : `$html = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $html));`
Didn't you mean something like `$html = stripslashes(str_replace('"', '\"', $html));`

Comment: ... Or rather use `\"` to keep double quotes, as originally intended: `"... \"ACQUISTA ..."`

Comment: i tried replacing the " of AQUISTA and from NEGOZIO, and still not working.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, i read it wrong. I edit my answer right know. He just mixed the string to search for and the one to replace.

Comment: @marchu how did you replace them ? I think your code's main problem is that you wrote the replacement ('\"" before the string you wanna replace '"') you should write str_replace(stringToReplace,Replacement, text)

Comment: @Carele like so: $html = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', "\'", $html));

Comment: @Marchu Man I think you don't really understand how the escape works... Apologize because i confused you by making a mistake first. With the code you are using you search for `\"` in your string. But there are no escaped quotes as long as you haven't created them. You must search `"` and replace them with `\"` Try :  `$html = stripslashes(str_replace('"', '\"', $html));` and tell me if it works !

Comment: In the original json that i downloaded there where the \ but i posted it on stackOverflow without. My bad. Nevermind, i already found the error. Thanks a lot for the help! @Carele

Answer (score 0):

```
"DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup":"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio "ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon."
```

Above script has `"` within string which is invalid JSON format. To make it correct put a slash before `"` within string like this.

```
"DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup":"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio \"ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO\" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon."
```

Valid JSON would be:

```
{  
   "easyStoreRelayList":[  

   ],
   "DecathlonStoreAreaNoStoreInGroup":"Nella zona che hai selezionato nessun negozio Decathlon al momento effettua il servizio \"ACQUISTA ON LINE RITIRA IN NEGOZIO\" oppure non sono presenti negozi Decathlon.",
   "warehouseRelayList":[  

   ],
   "DecathlonStoreAreaRememberMe":"Riconoscimi alla prossima visita",
   "DecathlonWarehouseParcelSection":"Magazzini",
   "DecathlonStoreParcelSection":"Negozio DECATHLON",
   "DecathlonEasyStoreParcelSection":"Negozio DECATHLON EASY",
   "geoName":"Alessandria",
   "physicalStoreList":[  
      [  
         "PS_IT_45",
         "Serravalle Scrivia (Alessandria)",
         "471",
         null,
         "7",
         null
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: Note that you should never edit the *code* in questions.

Comment: I haven't edited the answer!! Edited for good readability of JSON string. Please check before you make any comment! String was the SAME.

Comment: I was talking about your [suggested edit on the *question*](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12720514). There is a community consensus which says you should *never* edit code in questions, but no worries, I just told you that so you'd know.